# Jenkins Pipeline - job fails if script doesn't find any changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm working with jenkins job, which gets directories where changes were made to later run `terragrunt plan` in this directories. To get these changes I use:

```
def directories = sh([script: "git diff HEAD~1 --name-only | xargs dirname | sort | uniq | grep terragrunt/okta", returnStdout: true]).trim()
```

I'm using `grep` to get only directories where `.hcl` files are stored and it looks like if in these directories (`terragrunt/okta`) are no changes this script doesn't work and fails a build. Unfortunately I don't get any more information in my console output:

```
+ git diff HEAD~1 --name-only
+ xargs dirname
+ sort
+ uniq
+ grep terragrunt/okta
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Pull Terragrunt)
Stage "Pull Terragrunt" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
```

It's weird, because if I use this command in my console (without `returnStdout` and `trim` function it works, but in jenkins pipeline with these methods it makes a problem. Is there any way to deal with this problem/exception?

EDIT: SOLUTION

I dealt with this problem by adding `||` for `grep` - if this script doesn't return anything from grep then I use `echo ''`

Answer (score 0):

Try without `trim` in Jenkins. If you trim you assume some output is always there. Maybe that is not the case here.